# SQL Inner Join Sum (Referencing another column)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm working on an SQL query in which the end result is to have a column with a sum in it, using Table 1 and Table 2.

**Table 1:** Members:

```
    Level
    Individual
    Super
```

**Table 2:** MLevel:

```
    Level . . . . . Fee
    Super . . . . . 700
    Individual .. . 400
```

Giving value to the levels in column 1: 700 + 400 + 700 = 1800

**Desired Result:**

```
    Total . . . . . 1800
```

My Code:

**1st code attempt:**

```
SELECT SUM(Members.Level) as TotalRevenue
FROM MLevel 
INNER JOIN Members ON Members.Level = MLevel.Level
```

**Result:** Data type mismatch in criteria expression

**2nd code attempt:**

```
SELECT SUM(MLevel.Fee) as TotalRevenue
FROM MLevel 
INNER JOIN Members ON MLevel.Level= Members.Level
```

**Result:** pop-up box (Enter Parameter Value of MLevel.Fee)

All code results are wrong. How would I fix this code so that the output is 1800?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on the table structures and datatypes but I just tested the following in `MS Access 2003` and the using the following worked:

```
Members table:
Level
Individual
Super

MLevel Table:
Level       Fee
Super       700
Individual  400

SELECT SUM(MLevel.Fee) as TotalRevenue
FROM MLevel 
INNER JOIN Members ON Members.Level = MLevel.Level
```

using the query gives me a sum of 1100 since I only have 2 entries in Members, adding more increases the sum correctly.

Your first query will not work because the datatype on the `Members.Level` is a text field, so you get the datatype mismatch because the Level in Members is not numeric.

```
SELECT SUM(Members.Level) as TotalRevenue
FROM MLevel 
INNER JOIN Members ON Members.Level = MLevel.Level
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a sum on the fee column in table 2

so alias the second table then reference the alias.columnName in your sum statement